# Usage of 'do' and 'does'

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, do-support

I have heard the phrase:

> Do such easy questions really come?

What if I am pointing to a single question and asking:

> Does such an easy question really come?

I feel that the second sentence is not correct. Will there be any sentence used in this context beginning with 'does'.Or do we always have to use 'do' in this context.

Comment: They are both correct, because as you point out, the singular takes *does*: "it does."  But we don't really say that "questions come".  It would sound more fluent to use the [phrasal verb *come up*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/come-up): "Do such easy questions really *come up*?"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not the upmost expert on grammar rules, but I believe that both of those sentences are correct in terms of the Do/Does part (as for the sentence overall, I'm not entirely certain what the meaning is meant to be, it sounds a little funky). But for some examples that might sound a little more normal:

If someone asks you to, say, find some sort of people:

> Do such people exist?

Or maybe they just ask you to find one of that sort of person:

> Does such a person exist?

Answer (score 1):

'Does' is the 3rd-person singular form of the verb 'do'. All plural forms, regardless of person perspectives, are 'do'.
So if you say 'question**s**', it's plural form and 'do' is used, while when saying 'a question', it's singular form, thus uses the 3rd-person 'does' form.